# ndarray view into slices/indices

Tags: python, numpy

With an `ndarray.view`, one can do:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(6)
b = a.view()
b[...] = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

`a` and `b` are now both `[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]`.

Now, can I do the same with slicing/indexing? So that the view does not show the full array, but just a slice? Something like:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(6)
idx = [0, 2, 4]
b = a[idx] # please just return a view into `a` here
b[...] = [5, 5, 5]
```

Now `a` is of course still `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` but I'd like to have it to be `[5, 1, 5, 3, 5, 5]`.

This would be very useful when mapping between different arrays.

Comment: You can get views when working with indices that have a patterned strides. So, we can certainly get a view with `idx = [0, 2, 4]`, but not for a generic one.

Comment: Too bad, but that's basically what I expected. I think it would make sense to turn your comment into an answer, particularly for the next one with the same question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, we can get views when dealing with patterned strides for indexing.

Let's take a look at few cases.

1) Case #1: Starting `index = 0` and with a stride of `2`:

```
In [129]: a = np.arange(6)  # Input array

In [130]: idx = [0,2,4] # Simulating these indices for indexing

In [131]: b = a[::2]  # Get view

In [132]: b[...] = [5, 5, 5] # Assign values

In [133]: a
Out[133]: array([5, 1, 5, 3, 5, 5]) # Verify
```

2) Case #2: Starting `index = 1` and with a stride of `2`:

```
In [134]: a = np.arange(6)  # Input array

In [135]: idx = [1,3,5] # Simulating these indices for indexing

In [136]: b = a[1::2]  # Get view

In [137]: b[...] = [5, 5, 5] # Assign values

In [138]: a  
Out[138]: array([0, 5, 2, 5, 4, 5]) # Verify
```

This method is extensible to multi-dimensional arrays.